# Store date into MySQL database after form submit

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Here is my code, there are few before but here is the main code.

When i click **Complete Order** my database records `amazon_code` in db but i am trying to record `gift_pin` & `gift_card_name` these two data as well. When pressing **Complete Order** i need these two data added in db directly. please help

```html
<?php if (isset($this->data['amazon'])) { ?>
                             <input type="hidden" id="payment_method" value="amazon" />
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group" id="group-amazon_code">
                                            <label class="col-xs-12  form-control-label">Gift Card Number:
                                                <span class="muted small">(this is the code under the scratch off area)</span>
                                            </label>
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <input type="text" autocomplete="yes" value="" class="form-control" name="amazon_code" id="amazon_code" placeholder="Amazon Gift card # (under scratch off)" />
                                                <label for="amazon_code" class="error">Error Text</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                         <div class="form-group" id="group-amazon_code">
                                            <label class="col-xs-12  form-control-label">PIN</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <input type="text" autocomplete="yes" value="" class="form-control" name="gift_pin" id="gift_pin" placeholder="Enter PIN #" />
                                                <label for="gift_pin" class="error">Error Text</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                        <div class="form-group">
      <label for="human" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Gift Card Name:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
                         <select class="form-control" name="gift_card_name">
                             <option <?php if($this->data['gift_card_name'] == 'PayPal') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="PayPal">PayPal</option>
                                <option <?php if($this->data['gift_card_name'] == 'eBay') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="eBay">eBay</option>
                                <option <?php if($this->data['gift_card_name'] == 'Google') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="Google">Google</option>
                                <option <?php if($this->data['gift_card_name'] == 'iTunes') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="iTunes">iTunes</option>
                                <option <?php if($this->data['gift_card_name'] == 'BestBuy') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="BestBuy">BestBuy</option>
                            <option <?php if($this->data['gift_card_name'] == 'Hotels.com') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="Hotels.com">Hotels.com</option>
                            <option <?php if($this->data['gift_card_name'] == 'Bass Pro') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="Bass Pro">Bass Pro</option>
                            </select>
      </div>
     </div>
     
     
                                        
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            <?php } // End of Amazon?>


                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="alert alert-info">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                <div class="panel">
                                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                                        <h4 class="text-center">Credits</h4>
                                                        <h2 class="credits_text credits text-center"></h2>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                <div class="panel">
                                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                                        <h4 class="text-center">Order Total</h4>
                                                        <h2 class="price_text text-success text-center"></h2>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <!-- STEP 3 -->


                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix block"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg prev-btn">Previous Step</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-6">
                <a href="#" class=" btn btn-block btn-lg btn-success next-btn">Next Step</a>
                <a href="#hasErrors" class=" btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary finish-btn" data-submit="<?php echo (isset($this->data['amazon'])) ? 'amazonprocess' : 'process'; ?>">
                    <span class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    Complete Order
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You haven't shown any code relating to adding data to the database.

Comment: is it possible to place my sql connect code in this file and force those two fields to be stored in db directly?

Comment: Well, I am assuming in the code somewhere you have something that relates to `$_POST['amazon_code']` since you said that works perfectly. Do the same for `$_POST['gift_pin']` and `$_POST['gift_card_name']`.

Comment: Okay, so. The problem we have with answering is that we don't see any real backend code here. We can't see anything related to even adding to the database. If you want to add, just do a simple $_POST['gift_pin'] (sanitizing of course to protect from sql injection, and checking if it was set) and save it as an int. Save the name as a Varchar.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['gift_pin']) && isset($_POST['gift_card_name'])){

$giftPin = $_POST['gift_pin']; //Sanitize it too.
$giftCardName = $_POST['gift_card_name']; //Sanitize it too.



/*
    *  INCASE YOU MISSED IT: SANITIZE YOUR INPUTS. OR ELSE PEOPLE CAN USE
    *  SQL INJECTION TO STEAL ALL OF YOUR DATA, AND MAKE YOU LOOK LIKE A 
    *  FOOL. PREPARED STATEMENTS SHOULD BE USED WHEREVER POSSIBLE, Thanks
    */


//Add in all your other stuff you want in the database too.
$query = "INSERT INTO ultraCoolTable (gift_pin, gift_card_name) VALUES (" . $giftPin . ", '" . $giftCardName . "');";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

//Normal Stuff you'd do here, redirect maybe, check if it was added maybe. Whatever you want.

}else{
  //Something wasn't filled in, you should ideally not allow them to click  the button by adding the required attribute to all the fields necessary but hey-ho... better redirect them or something (:
}
```

Also your title is mis-spelt giving the illusion that it was the date you wanted to be added to the database. For anyone wondering about adding a date, in your php script add a `BIGINT` to your database from the `microseconds(true);` method.

Comment: Emphasizing the importance of `//Sanitize it too.` to anyone reading, you really should be using prepared statements as well.

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for your help, i really appreciate that.

Here is the code that submit the form and i think i have to put your code inside this existing code. but i am not sure how to do that. can you please put your code inside these following existing codes?

Existing codes:

<a href="#hasErrors" class=" btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary finish-btn" data-submit="<?php echo (isset($this->data['amazon'])) ? 'amazonprocess' : 'process'; ?>">
                    <span class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    Complete Order
                </a>